# choosing cloud for jee6 application

Tags: amazon-web-services, java-ee-6, jboss7.x, openshift

we are building a jee6 application in jboss 7.1 as, and now we need to deploy  a production infrastructure; i have doubts about how to  use the services in the cloud, though my first idea was to use openshift to deploy the java application, I would like to know your thoughts about if it´s a good idea or if i should use ec2  even when I have no experience configuring production environments?
also I would like to know if the mysql (open shift) service is good for a production application or if I should use amazon rds or another database service?
Finally, how can I manage files in open shift? amazon s3 or another easy way?

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Openshift is great for dev & QA since you really don't have to worry about a lot of infrastructure aspects including

1. Installation
2. Configuration
3. Patching / Upgrading
4. Management
5. Load balancing

I also like Openshift for various reasons. They give you the option of choosing your language / framework of Choice.

Whether its ready for production, it depends on how you architect your application. Openshift actually puts its workload on EC2 behind the scenes so you get similar SLA's as EC2.

If you are able to create a highly available application that's deployed on different nodes, you eliminate a single point of failure but if EC2 is down (taking down all the nodes), I am not really sure how Openshift handles those scenarios.

Of all the public PaaS offerings, Openshift is definitely my favorite.

MySQL should be no different from JBoss, in this environment. Everything that applies for JBoss also applies for MySQL.

Good luck and please do post your findings here.